# variable seen by all classes Java

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in java, so I don't know if there is any way to make a variable seen by all classes in same package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default modifier (just don't write `public`/`private`/`protected`) gives access from inside the package only. (Take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html))

But as a rule, it is a good practice to avoid accessing variables directly.

**Edit:**

Responding the comments, if you want to access this variable without creating an object, then it should be static:

```
package com.some.package;
public class MyClass {
    static int someInt = 1;
}
```

Then to access it, you need to qualify it by the class:

```
package com.some.package;
public class AnotherClass {
    public void someMethod() {
        int i = MyClass.someInt;
              //^^^^^^^
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I did this and the variable still unknow for the 2nd class:
// in first class 
public int casedurationpublic;
// in Second class 
int i = 2 - casedurationpublic;

Answer (score 0):

static <type> <variable name>;

If you do not supply access modifier, it defaults to package-private. It means that the variable is visible only to members of the same package.

Comment: What does `static` has to do with it? The access rules of modifiers apply to instance-members as well as static members.

Comment: He wrote "by all classes" so I assumed he wanted a static access. The static can of course be omitted.